# How to calculate average wind speed at a particular location (given longitude and latitude)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, interpolation, netcdf

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and new to this software. My question iss

1. I have time series wind speed data in netCDF form. I extract netCDF in raster form after that in table form. Now I need How to calculate average wind speed at a particular location (given longitude and latitude)?
2. how interpolate different locations wind speed?

Comment: Are your locations polygons or points? Is the speed data a single value, or are there multiple values per cell (ie, four different speed readings for the same cell)? What do you mean by 'interpolate different locations' - the raster should allow you to get a speed at any given location as it is a continuous surface. Do you have points (geometry) for locations, or just coordinate pairs (based on your statement of a given lat/lon)?

Comment: If you can edit your question to include more information, we may be able to provide more help. As written, it's a bit unclear.